# Why stringlib algorithm of Python was called "BMHBNFS"?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, abbreviation

[This algorithm](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm#BMHBNFS) contains Boyer-Moor, Horspool, Sunday and Bloom filter.

Why use "BMHBNFS" instead of "BM-H-S-BF" ?

Comment: That looks like the name of the algorithm as chosen by the author, they can call it whatever they want.  It's not exposed as the name of a function, is it?  If it is then they couldn't put dashes in the name.

Comment: My guess is that it stands for BMH By "Need For Speed". BMH is a common acronym for this family of algorithms, and you don't often find it extended with the initials of other authors.

Comment: The provided link in web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20201107074620/http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm

Comment: I have read it before post the question actually.